# Create Context-Sensitive Menus in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I found this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/Cc514027 to help me create a menu.

I followed the tutorial step by step. I have the two red boxes, but I am unable to right click on the two boxes to have the menu show.

When I debug I end up with error code C2084: function 'void CContextMenusView::OnContextMenu(CWnd*, CPoint)' already has a body.

```
  // CContextMenusView message handlers
   void CContextMenusView::OnContextMenu(CWnd* /*pWnd*/, CPoint point)
```

{
    //TODO: Add your message handler code here

```
CMenu PopupMenu;
CPoint ptClient;
m_nBox = -1;

ptClient = point;
ScreenToClient(&ptClient);

if (rect1.PtInRect(ptClient))
    m_nBox = 0;
else if (rect2.PtInRect(ptClient))
    m_nBox = 1;

if (m_nBox != -1)
{
    if (PopupMenu.LoadMenu(IDR_CONTEXTMENU))
    {
        CMenu* pPopupMenu = PopupMenu.GetSubMenu(0);
        if (point.x == -1 && point.y == -1)
        {
            point.x = 5;
            point.y = 5;
            ClientToScreen(&point);
        }
        pPopupMenu->TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON,
            point.x, point.y, this);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: That's not a debug error, that's a compile-time error meaning that there are two implementations of the OnContextMenu function in the same file. You must remove the 'other' of them.

Comment: Oh perfect! I understand and see what you are saying. I just removed void CContextMenusView::OnContextMenu(CWnd* /* pWnd */, CPoint point)
{
#ifndef SHARED_HANDLERS
 theApp.GetContextMenuManager()->ShowPopupMenu(IDR_POPUP_EDIT, point.x, point.y, this, TRUE);
#endif
}